# A simple way to create static imports for constants in existing code?

Tags: java, eclipse

If I have a constant BAR in Foo, which I will use in a class C I'll have to write

```
Object o = Foo.BAR + "...";
```

which I can use Ctrl-Shift-M in Eclipse (with the cursor on BAR) to create a static import for like:

```
import static Foo.BAR;

Object o = BAR + "....";
```

I am current updating legacy code with literaly thousands of these I'd like to convert to static imports.  Ctrl-Shift-O / Organize imports does not do it.  Is there a trick I've missed?

---

EDIT:  Actually, what I would prefer is a way to tell Eclipse that I want to have Ctrl-Shift-M do its magic on ALL instances in this particular class instead of just the single instance I have the cursor placed at.    (It is legacy code so this actually IMPROVES readability :) )

---

EDIT:  I've found that IntelliJ suggest doing this.

Comment: +1 For simply mentioning Ctrl-Shift-M

Comment: BTW: For those stumbling over here: ctrl-shift-m works for exactly this, place cursor on BAR, press it and you have your static import (tested in eclipse luna) even better described here: http://www.codeaffine.com/2012/03/28/how-do-you-import-static-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One cautionary note: excessive use of static imports can actually make your code less readable (imho), particularly if the constant name doesn't clearly indicate the class or enum from which it belongs. You can also get constant names from different classes/enums that sound similar or even have the same name.

So what you're forcing the reader to do is hope his IDE will tell him the class (via, say, a tool tip) or they have to navigate to it to find out what it is. Printouts and code snippets become that much less reeadable.

Honestly I use static imports extremely rarely for these reasons.

Comment: I am aware of these things.  In this particular case I have a keyholder class with key constants used everywhere - hence your concern is not an issue, rather the contrary :D

Comment: When the question is "how do I do this with static imports", I don't think that "don't use static imports" is an answer worth up-voting.

Comment: Protecting people from well-intentioned but misguided ends is a time-honoured technique in answering questions.

Comment: I believe this is also the reason why the Pascal construction "with" is not a part of Java.  You lose context.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: does that mean you don't gonna change this anymore? does cletus convinced you?

Comment: @Tim, no I was not convinced, but all other answers suggested running external programs which is _worse_...

Comment: I disagree - I think static importing all constants makes the code MORE readable. Sacrificing real code conciseness and readability to improve printouts and code snippets is ludicrous. Most of the time the name of the constant is enough - if I want to find out where it comes from it is not hard to find it with an IDE.

Comment: Just trying to understand things no offense meant.....how does this answer the actual question!question was to find a simple way to convert all the instances to static imports , but this is more of a decision making what cletus has explained.

Comment: @Ravisha, the acceptance does not indicate that the answer fully, accurately answers the question, but that it was the most helpful.  Or least unhelpful :)

Comment: There are plenty of fluent libraries where static imports are essential for readability (e.g. Mockito, Hamcrest, Fest). I use eclipse favorites to easily manage static imports in these cases, but a way to convert all qualified instances in a class would certainly be useful.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any other automated refactorings to do what you're looking for, but there are two key aspects to doing this - one is adding the imports and the other is removing the class name from the constants.

For adding the imports, I recommend pasting `import static application.KeyHolder.*;` after the package on every file which uses them.

For removing the class name, in eclipse do a Java search for `KeyHolder.*` and search for a field.  You can then do a find/replace for "KeyHolder." and replace with "".  In order to prevent mismatches make sure the replaced item count is equal to the number of matches for that file.  Also, make sure you search down and start after the imports.

Comment: If you import static application.KeyHolder.* and then press ctrl-shift-O that will convert your import to a number of lines, 1 for each constant you use in your code.

Comment: Actually it's a configurable option in eclispe. You can state the number of static imports you want before it uses a "star" import. I think the default is 8. I have lowered it to 3 for my use.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expression was invented to solve problems like these! =)

you will need to write a small script (or use the IDE regex search/replace). The only problem is that if there are lots of classes that needs to be statically imported, then its just as much work. Otherwise, if its just one class like FOO.BLAH, then you can use a regex like

`(\bFOO\.(\w+)\b)` -> replace with group 2 ($2 or \2 or however your regex searcher does capture replaces).

you can try it here : http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ . Select the replace tab and type in $2

A problem might arise if you have expressions like this though: 
`FOO f = FOO.blah + "FOO.blah"` , so watch out for that.

As for the import statement at the top of the file, eclipse has an auto import feature where it does autoimport on format, and it works as long as the name of the import is unique enough. Or, if you cant use it because the name is too common, you can just use a perl script to do the regex instead, and prepend the static imports.

Comment: And now you have two problems ;-)

Comment: Not using the refactoring tools inside Eclipse means that you disregard the knowledge that Eclipse has of your code, and only work on the textual representation of the raw source.  Sigh.

Comment: Well, sometimes the refactoring you want to do isnt supported inside eclipse (although i feel this particular usecase you have here ought to be supported)

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse can do a global search and replace with regular expression over all files in the project.

To add the static import at the beginning of all files you could replace the package declaration by itself plus the static import.

Then do a project wide organize imports, and you're all set.

Be careful, though, this could also make a big mess if you do it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a nice idea, but after you have changed all the files, how much better will they be? Perhaps you should think about only changing the files which you are working on for other reasons already.

Answer (score 0):

If I were faced with such a challenge, I'd probably write a small program to do it for me. Ruby and Python (JRuby and Jython?) are pretty well suited for the task, although you could do it in Java too.

OK, so that'll probably take you at least the same amout of time as doing it by hand, but at least you'll be having fun :).

Answer (score -1):

Well something which pops in as a solution. I would recommend using a simple groovy script. Basically the semantics are related to parsing the import statements and the files they refer to. Some basic steps could be like

1. Recurse each file inside directory.Check whether the file extension is .java
2. Match any line which starts with import
3. For each such line open the relevant source file(you already know the path from the import statement).
4. Match the field/method declaration for a static modifier using reflection
5. Add static after the import statement for matches found in step 5.

If i get some time i will try and post a small groovy script for doing the same.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure no conflicts with other constant classes

replace all the "Foo." with empty (" ")

use this line at the top. worked for me

import static Foo.*

Comment: This does not remove the "Foo." from the various places in the source file.

Comment: If Foo is a constant class how about replace all the "Foo." with empty (" ") and use above line at the top ?

Comment: Select “ Edit ” – > “ Find/Replace”, or press “ Ctrl+F ”. Use 'Foo' as the find text and  '' (empty) as the replace with text then click on replace All button. Then in the import section add       -   import static Foo.*   . Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, Every IDE support replace All function. Can't accept your point.

Comment: Doing this on a textual level completely misses the whole point of using an IDE.   What if this was the only thing from Foo I would like to import statically?

Comment: This is just a trick and may not be the geek way to do it. I think that this will help you when  literaly thousands of these and you don't want IDE other than eclipse and when your client or boss waiting for you to deliver the product quickly. You know the context better than me. So use only if you think this way is useful. Otherwise just forget it.

Comment: As the edited question say, I've since found that IntelliJ can do this. That's good enough for me.

Comment: my bad. I thought you know how to do it in Intellej and you want a way to do it in Eclipse

Comment: Sorry for not having phrased the question clearly enough. How could I have worded it to be clearer?

Comment: I think the question is clear but I misunderstood it.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know if it would fit your needs, but you can always have these constants defined in an interface and have all your classes just implement this interface. Then using some smart RegExp as others suggest you could get rid of all `Foo.` occurences.

Example:

```
public interface Foo {
   static final String constant1 = "Some";
   static final String constant2 = "Value";
   //...
}
```

And then

```
public class YourClass implements Foo {
   public YourClass() {
      System.out.println("Hello " + constant1);
   }
}
```

Comment: that would be a horrible way to code - do not create and implement interfaces just to access static final constants.

Comment: I know it. I was just following OP's idea. Thanks anyway.