# How to change java.sql.Connection con; to import declaration and Connection con;

Tags: java, eclipse, import

As the title says, I would like to know how to change:
java.sql.Connection con = ...;
into
import java.sql.Connection;
...
Connection con = ...;

Using Eclipse settings for imports would be great.

Connection is just an example of this "direct access".

Finally if you know the name of that system add it to the answer.

Thanks in advance.

--Edit:
Thanks to BalusC for the proper naming, I found [Simplifying fully qualified names in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644440/simplifying-fully-qualified-names-in-eclipse) but there isn't a way yet.

Answer (score 2):

In the line,

```
java.sql.Connection con = ...;
```

put the cursor on the classname `Connection` and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (*Add Import*). Eclipse will convert the fully qualified name to a short name and add an import if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
...
Connection con = ...
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what the OP is concretely asking.

Comment: Thank you domvoyt, I already know that, but I'm working at a (legacy) project as freelancer coder and I wanted a way to do it for the whole project at once, like "Organize Imports" option at Eclipse.